# Implementing Push button as ON/OFF Toggle

Tags: flipflop, toggle-switch

Here is the flow:

1) Push button once to start the motor.
2) Push button again to stop the motor.
3) Push button again to Start the motor.
. . .and so on

I am trying to implement this with flip-flops but cannot figure out the correct logic.
TIA

[image: Notice the button(open cylinder block) and accompanying flip-flop in the red box]

Comment: Show us the logic you have tried. There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar and logic symbols are included.

Comment: Feed switch to a one-shot like the 74121 or 74123, then drive toggle FF from that?

Comment: If this is homework, try what you did (like Transistor just commented), if it is not homework, there are switches which have this behavior physically inside.

Comment: a push button connected to the (rising edge triggered) CLK pin of a T Flip Flop, and T input is Vcc so that it will toggle everytime you press the button and make a low to high transiton(rising edge) for CLK pin. Of course, this will suffer from button debouncing.

Comment: Let me try to create a quick logic diagram of have I have tried!

Comment: Added a  picture of my logic block diagram. The Bistable trigger is basically a RS flip-flop. In the current configuration I am starting the motor on button press (open cylinder block) and keeping it on till the linear sensor readout is greater than 0.  
What I need to do here is that if i press the same button again, the motor should stop.

Comment: As for my background, I am doing this as a hobby project to relive my electronics engineering days and in the process educate my kids about logic control etc!

Comment: The processing unit used here is from CAN IO14+ that i got from a friend's dead boat

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common requirement for many logic solutions.
In TTL logic you'd use a [74LS74 or 74HC74](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc74-ep.pdf?ts=1591292722784), but you can't beat a CMOS solution such as shown below based on the [CD4013](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4013b.pdf?ts=1591292792623)

I'll leave you work through the logic as a challenge, but note that U1a is used as an RS flip/flip and U1b used as a Dtype Toggle with reset.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOuiEJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
*** I have not shown power supply caps here or the supply to the VCC/Gnd to the IC.

It's worth noting that a CD4013 will cost you > $0.50  plus discrete components and you can get an ATTiny10 for $0.33.
As an exercise using the CD4013 (or 74xx74) on a breadboard may be valid, but it makes no sense when designing product. You'd learn much more using a small MCU.

Comment: Thank you Jack! I am actually using a MCU.